# Considering $g = \pi$ and its approximation $g_h = \frac{22}{7}$ find the absolute error and relative error.

Tags: numerical-methods

Considering $g = \pi$ and its approximation $g_h = \frac{22}{7}$ I am trying to find the absolute error and relative error.

Here are my workings, this is the first tie doing this sort of problem so I am not sure if this is correct or not.

$$E_{abs} = \left|\pi - \frac{22}{7}\right| = 0.00126 \approx 0.0013$$

$$E_{rel} = \left| \frac{\pi - \frac{22}{7}}{\pi}\right| = 0.000402 \approx. 0.0004$$

Looking to see if these workings are correct, thanks!

Comment: So what is the motivation for your question, exactly? Do you not know (or are you not sure of) the definition(s)? These are correct, but I don't think you're going to learn anything from that.

Comment: sorry I am just checking to see if my workings were correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the definitions of absolute and relative error correctly.

One criticism: I suggest you modify your notation to show that the error is not *exactly* $0.000402$, perhaps by using ellipsis.

$$E_{rel} = \left| \frac{\pi - \frac{22}{7}}{\pi}\right| = 0.000402\color{red}{\dots} \approx 0.0004$$

Comment: yes you are right I should of used the ellipsis or the approx. again. Thanks for your help!